# How to Pass API in VBA ACCESS

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, sms

Does anybody know how to use this is VBA ACCESS?

I am using this reference: https://semaphore.co/docs

This is sample code in .NET:

```vb
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] response =
    client.UploadValues("https://semaphore.co/api/v4/messages", new NameValueCollection()
    {
        { "apikey", "" },
        { "number", "09998887777" },
        { "message", "I just sent my first message with Semaphore" },
        { "sendername", "SEMAPHORE" },
    });
   string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
}`
```

I am actually new to this, so advice would be a great help

Comment: to do a post request in access vba you add a reference to the microsoft winHttp library.  From the code editor go to the ribbon and select tools-references.  Documentation is sparse, but there are many examples.  However, I did not do well hunting for examples: https://vbaplanet.com/libwinhttp.php  ,  https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29165302/Use-MS-Access-VBA-to-create-http-post-request.html